# How to listen native and custom javascript events inside Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom

I'm trying to get a native javascript event listener inside an AngularJs controller. I don't try to explain why but I cant' understand how to solve this.

I've created the custom event like this:

```
var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
event.initEvent('custom-event', true, true);
document.dispatchEvent(event);
```

and inside the angular controller:

```
angular.module('uploadCtrl', [])
  .controller('uploadController', ['$scope', '$window', '$compile', function($scope, $window, $compile, $http, Video) {
    document.addEventListener('custom-event', function(e) {
      console.log('event received');
    })
  }]);
```

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that the controller code is not going to execute until the DOM is ready.  Without more code, it's hard to say what your issue is specifically, but I'll bet that you're firing off that event before the controller's wired up a listener.  Take a look at this, which works.

```
(function(window, angular) {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('Test', [])
    .controller('UploadCtrl', ['$window', function($window) {
      $window.document.addEventListener('custom-event', function(e) {
      $window.console.log('event received');
    });
  }]);

  window.setTimeout(() => {
    const event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
    event.initEvent('custom-event', true, true);
    document.dispatchEvent(event);
  }, 0);
})(window, window.angular);
```

Note that this code is just for demonstration purposes.  The `setTimeout`' is only used to show that the event listener will handle the event, and that the OP's code is suffering from a race condition.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I've noticed that I didn't load the controller inside the application. Thanks mate

Comment: No problem.  If my answer helped, please consider marking it as the answer.